# Doxygen show brief summary of functions

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to have doxygen show a brief summary of the function in `Files->File Members->Functions'

For Example:

I want this:

`Box_The_Function_Name() : doxygen_c.h`

to look like this

`Box_The_Function_Name() : doxygen_c.h : brief explanation`

Doxygen does this automatically for structs but not functions.

Any ideas ?

Comment: _"Doxygen does this automatically for structs but not functions."_ Does it? I don't see any structs on this page. I get functions, variables and defines only. Doxygen 1.6.1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You addressed my misconception in your answer, I was talking about the classes page.

Comment: Okay good stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doxygen does this automatically for structs but not functions.

No, it doesn't. Classes/types are not represented on this page at all, but instead in the list of classes, which is a completely different page with a different paradigm.

On *this* page, where functions, variables and defines are listed, the nature of translation units means that the same name could be found in multiple files, e.g.:

```
Box_The_Function_Name() : A.h , B.h, C.h
```

Here's a real-world example from my commercial project (don't tell anyone):

```
parse_options() : debug-register-reader.cpp , main.cpp , metrics-converter.cpp , debug-register-writer.cpp
```

The function `parse_options()` in each file is different, and may have a different summary text. It would not be very user-friendly if Doxygen tried to cram each summary text into a list here.

So, no, you can't do this.

However, you can simply click on the filename to go to the documentation for the function as found in that file.